# How do I match a string until certain pattern that also works when the pattern does not show up?

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract numbers followed by an A, until pattern " X " appears:

```
"50A ABC DE 51A FG X 52A HI 53A"
```

The regex `\d+A(?=.* X )` correctly matches `50A` and `51A`, because they appear before  `X`
, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/ohRR2Q/1).

However, if a string does not have the `X` pattern, the regex won´t match any of the desired pattens (50A, 51A, 52A and 53A)

```
"50A ABC DE 51A FG 52A HI 53A"    # no X here
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex like

```r
\G(?:(?! X ).)*?\K\b\d+A\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UOqb5l/1). *Details*:

- `\G` - start of string or end of the previous successful match (to only ensure consecutive matches)
- `(?:(?! X ).)*?` - any char, other than line  break char, as few as possible, that does not start a space+`X`+space char sequence
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `\b\d+A\b` - one or more digits and `A` inside word boundaries.

In R, you can use [the following base R code](https://ideone.com/S6ZAm2):

```r
x <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG 52A HI 53A"
rx <- "\\G(?:(?! X ).)*?\\K\\b\\d+A\\b"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(rx, x, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "50A" "51A" "52A" "53A"
x <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG X 52A HI 53A"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(rx, x, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "50A" "51A"
```

You can remove all after an `X` word, and then extract:

```r
x <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG X 52A HI 53A"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(sub("(\\s|^)X(\\s.*)?$", "", x), "\\b\\d+A\\b")
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "50A" "51A"

x <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG 52A HI 53A"
str_extract_all(sub("(\\s|^)X(\\s.*)?$", "", x), "\\b\\d+A\\b")
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "50A" "51A" "52A" "53A"
```

Here,

- `sub("(\\s|^)X(\\s.*)?$", "", x)` removes `X` at the start of string or after  a whitespace (with this whitespace) and optionally followed with whitespace and any text at the end of the string
- `str_extract_all(..., "\\b\\d+A\\b")` extracts one or more digits followed with `A` as whole words in the remaining string part.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be matching  `X`  and from that point on avoid matching the rest of the like using SKIP FAIL and enable PCRE using `perl=T`

```
X .*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d+A\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `X`  Match literally
- `.*(*SKIP)(*F)` Match the rest of the line to avoid matching it
- `|` Or
- `\b\d+A\b` Match 1+ digits and `A` between word boundaries

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b5EP2G/1) and a [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOLq9hQwUZXQcnUwFHB0clZwcVVwdTQUcHNXSFCwdTIUcHDU8HU2FGJq9gIhzJkRQWJJSVgZREKeloaWsHengGaGlpumjUxMUkxMSnajkBaiYurKDU9N7EkOSO1WKPYUEchHchPrSgo0gBp11EACRWkFuXYhmhqoig1wlRqhFD6/z8A).

Example

```
library(stringr)

s1 <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG X 52A HI 53A"
s2 <- "50A ABC DE 51A FG 52A HI 53A"
patt <- "X .*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b\\d+A\\b"

regmatches(s1, gregexpr(patt, s1, perl=T))
regmatches(s2, gregexpr(patt, s2, perl=T))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "50A" "51A"

[[1]]
[1] "50A" "51A" "52A" "53A"
```